# Css classes : menu pop up dont work using .active

Tags: css

Having this code the ".active" function on click doesnt work but if i change the div class="top-menu-popup" with div class="top-menu-popup active" when i open the page , the menu is already activated.

```
<div class="top-menu-popup">
            <div class="top-menu-arrow" style="margin-right: 17.5px;"></div>
            <div class="top-menu-item home" style="display: block;">Homepage</div>
            <div class="context-menu-divider homepage" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div class="top-menu-item contains-submenu">
                "MASINI"
                <div class="top-submenu-popup">
                    <div class="top-menu-item volkswagen">Volkswagen</div>
                    <div class="top-menu-item mercedes">Mercedes</div>
                    <div class="top-menu-item ford">Ford Mustang</div>
                    <div class="top-menu-item ferrari">Ferrari</div>
                    <div class="top-menu-item dodge">Dodge</div>
                    <div class="top-menu-item lincoln">Lincoln</div>
                    <div class="top-menu-item jaguar">Jaguar</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

.top-menu-popup {
    min-width: 178px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 500;
    padding: 5px 0;
    min-height: 40px;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
}

.top-menu-popup.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You getting any errors in your console?

Comment: please show us you javascript code

Comment: No, 0 errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

I am just taking a guess, but i assume you mean the `::active` pseudo class:

```css
.top-menu-popup {
    min-width: 178px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 500;
    padding: 5px 0;
    min-height: 40px;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
}

html:active .top-menu-popup {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
Click Anywhere...
<div class="top-menu-popup">
            <div class="top-menu-arrow" style="margin-right: 17.5px;"></div>
            <div class="top-menu-item home" style="display: block;">Homepage</div>
            <div class="context-menu-divider homepage" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div class="top-menu-item contains-submenu">
                "MASINI"
                <div class="top-submenu-popup">
                    <div class="top-menu-item volkswagen">Volkswagen</div>
                    <div class="top-menu-item mercedes">Mercedes</div>
                    <div class="top-menu-item ford">Ford Mustang</div>
                    <div class="top-menu-item ferrari">Ferrari</div>
                    <div class="top-menu-item dodge">Dodge</div>
                    <div class="top-menu-item lincoln">Lincoln</div>
                    <div class="top-menu-item jaguar">Jaguar</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: sorry, the menu still dont pop up

Comment: Are you using JavaScript?

Comment: Now it works, but it pops up just for 1 sec and then it dissapear also is active when i just hold the mouse click.

Comment: That is what :active is supposed to do, if you want it to stay longer, use the :focus selector, JS, or a CSS checkbox hack

Comment: trying to use :focus on your answear and doesnt work

Comment: @clintrock for :focus, the element must have a tab-index

Comment: should be something like this ? html:focus .top-menu-popup {
    display: block;
}                            <div class="top-menu-popup" tabindex="0">

Comment: Hold on: .active != :active

Comment: ok, now im trying to use the js '$(function(){
  $('.top-menu-popup').click(function(){
   $('.top-menu-popup.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
  });
 });' but dont work

Answer (score 0):

- First, if you're creating a menu, where is the semantic tags nav, ul, ol or li tags?
- Second, you can simply try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpnepzdf/

With this basically you have a menu like this:

`<ul class="horz">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul class="vert">
            <li><a href="#">Sub item 11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub item 12</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul class="vert">
            <li><a href="#">Sub item 21</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub item 22</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>`

And then you can simply show the content with this CSS:

```
ul { margin:0; padding:0 }
.horz > li { display:inline-block; position:relative; padding:0 20px; }
.vert { margin-left:1rem; }
.vert li { line-height:100%; }

ul .vert {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    width:100%;
}

ul .vert li {
    padding:5px 0;
}

ul > li.active > .vert,
ul > li:hover > .vert {
    display: block; 
}

a:hover { color:red; }
```

Basically your `li` or your `div.top-menu-item.contains-submenu` will show up the content on :hover, you can also add a class `.active` to any `li` and it will show up the submenu permanently.